# Scrapy not following pagination links

Tags: pagination, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape news articles from https://www.finextra.com/latest-news

I've looked through similar questions on stackoverflow regarding scrapy pagination issues, but none seem to reflect my issue.

Everything in my code works except for the section where I want to follow 'next_page' links. I have written another spider for another news website using the exact same code (apart from the xpath selectors) and it works perfectly.

I've checked that the xpath selector is extracting the link correctly, and I've commented out allowed_domains due to some answers suggesting an issue with middleware.

Can someone help me please.

```
class FinextraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'finextra'
    # allowed_domains = ["finextra.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.finextra.com/latest-news"]

    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.xpath("//div[@class='module--story']")

        for article in articles:
            category = article.xpath("./div[@class='story--content']/h6/a/text()").get()
            category = category.replace("/", "")
            article_link = article.xpath("./div[@class='story--content']/h4/a/@href").get()
            title = article.xpath("./div[@class='story--content']/h4/a/text()").get()
            title = title.replace("'", "''")

            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(article_link),
                                  cb_kwargs={'category': category,
                                             'article_link': article_link,
                                             'title': title},
                                  callback=self.parse_readmore)

        # DOESNT WORK
        next_page = response.xpath("//div[@id='pagination']/a[last()-1]/@href")
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page,
                                  callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The script got stuck at `category = category.replace("/", "")` because a certain article did not have a category, therefore terminating the spider.

Adding an if else statement to continue if category is empty solved it.

Thank you to anyone who has read this.